# Include joined table columns in query dicts

Tags: python, peewee

I'm using `peewee` to query a database, and I'm returning the query using `.dicts()`, but for ForeignKeyFields I don't know how to include the foreign key in the resulting dict.

Code speaks louder than words:

```
from peewee import Model

class Foo:
    name = SomeField(unique=True)

class Bar:
    param_one = SomeField()
    param_two = SomeField()
    param_xyz = SomeField()
    a_foo = ForeignKeyField(Foo)

query = Bar.select().join(Foo).dicts()
for i in query:
   print(i['a_foo'].name)
   >> AttributeError

query = Bar.select(Bar.param_one, Foo.name).join(Foo).dicts()
for i in query:
   print(i)
   >>> {'param_one': x, 'name': y}
```

I'm wondering whether there's a way to do something similar to the second query but without having to type all of the column names in `Bar`.

I.e., output a dictionary which includes all columns in `Bar`, and the joined column in `Foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a short-hand to select all columns from a model:

```
query = Bar.select(Bar, Foo).join(Foo).dicts()
```

When using dicts, all the fields from Bar and Foo are present in the row dict. If Foo has fields that share the same name as a field in Bar, then the field from Foo will not be included as it would overwrite a field from Bar.